# Save correlation output from loop to matrix

Tags: r, loops, correlation

I have a setup that looks like below

```
for(V in (seq(1, 250, by = 5))){
   for(n in (seq(1, 250, by = 5))){

        # 1) Working Algorithm creating a probability 
             ie. vector in range [0:1] 

        # 2) Take the natural log of this probability 
        a <-  log(lag(Probability), base = exp(1))

        # 3) calculate price differences
        b <-  abs(diff(Price) -1)

        # 4) Then compute correlation between a and b
        cor(a, b) 

        # 5) Here I'd like to save this in the corresponding index of matrix
   }
}
```

So that I get a [V, n] sized matrix as output, that collects from each loop.

I have a few problems with this.

- The first problem is that my correlation is not computable, as the `Probability` is often 0, creating a `ln(0) = -Inf` input in the `ln(Probability)` vector. Is there a way to compute the `std.dev` or `cor` of a `Ln` vector with `-Inf` inputs?
- My second question is how I save this correlation output into a matrix generated for each loop?

Thanks for your help. I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Why are you taking the log of a variable that is often 0?

Comment: ...you could use log(x + 1) instead...

Comment: I added a +1, as you suggested. The correlation won't change if I add a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question (My second question is how I save this correlation output into a matrix generated for each loop?), you could initialise a matrix before the loop and store each computed correlation in the corresponding index like:

```
sz <- seq(1, 250, by = 5)
out_mat <- matrix(0, nrow=length(sz), ncol=length(sz))
# then continue with your for-loop
for (V in 1:length(sz)) {
    for(n in length(sz)) {
        # here instead of accessing V and n in computing probability
        # use sz[V] and sz[n]
        ...
        ...
        # after computing the correlation, here use V and n (not sz[V] or sz[n])
        out_mat[V, n] <- c # c holds the value of cor(a,b)
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting a 'subscript out of bounds' with this function. Would you know what is causing this error?

Comment: Yes, that was a silly mistake. Now, I've changed the code. See the inline comments. Basically, use this code and replace V and n everywhere with sz[V] and sz[n] except for `out_mat[V, n]`

Comment: I'm running it not and it seems to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm having a problem running your solution. I need the for loops of V and n to take on the number of the sequence of sz. If i use V in 1:length(sz) with sz equal to say seq(1, 10, by = 5) then V will take on 1 and 2, when it should be 1 and 6. I get an error when trying V in seq(1, 10, by = 5). Would you know what is causing the subscript out of bounds error?

Comment: I've said about this in my earlier comment and commented in the code. You can access the 1 and 6 by doing `sz[V]` and you can store in the matrix using `V = 1, 2`

Comment: The difference between the sz[V] and V had me confused. It is working as intended now. Thanks again.

Comment: glad you got it figured. I admit it could get confusing!

Answer (score 2):

What you can do with -Inf is replace that by NA, for example:

```
x = runif(10)
x[3] = 1/0
> is.infinite(x)
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x[is.infinite(x)] <- NA
> x
 [1] 0.09936348 0.66624531         NA 0.90689357 0.71578917 0.14655174
 [7] 0.59561047 0.41944552 0.67203026 0.03263173
```

And use the `na.rm` argument for `sd`:

```
>  sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0.3126829
```